# I can't get the appropriate results when filtering in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the following Linq-to-SQL code which compiles, but why is the variable `products`  not getting filled?

```
NorthwindDataContext ndc= new NorthwindDataContext();

var countries= new []{"Uk", "France" ," Germany"};

var productCountries =  from product in ndc.Products
                        join supplier in ndc.Suppliers 
                            on product.SupplierID equals supplier.SupplierID
                        select new {Product=product, Country= supplier.Country};

var products = from productCountry in productCountries
               where countries.Contains(productCountry.Country)
               select productCountry.Product;
```

I think it is because I have to fetch `productCountries` first with a foreach, I have tried to do it, inserting the result of the query I use in `productCountries` in a typed list of `Products`, but this is not working.

Can you help me to find out how can I get `products` filled?

Answer (score 0):

First of all for queries use SQL Profiler.

Also regarding queries
 where countries.Contains(productCountry.Country)
Seems this is not correct.

I haven't ran it yet but looking at queries it looks so.
you need to put where condition on the column of the table however you are doing on the array list.